# Proving $b^n-1$ is not a perfect square for any $b, n \geq 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, quadratic-residues

I am currently attempting to prove that $b^n - 1$ is not a perfect square for any integers $b$ and $n$ greater than 1. I've gotten most of the way using a straightforward argument using quadratic residues modulo 4 (which are 0 for even squares and 1 for odd squares):

1. If $b \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$, then $b^n - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, which is not a quadratic residue.
2. If $b \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, then $b^n \equiv 2^n \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ since $n \geq 2$, so $b^n - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ again.
3. If $b \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, then $b^n \equiv (-1)^n \pmod{4}$. If $n$ is odd, then $b^n - 1 \equiv -2 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$, which is not a quadratic residue. If $n$ is even, then $b^n$ is a perfect square, so $b^n - 1$ cannot be.

However, the case of $b\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ still remains. Clearly, $b$ is odd. Further, if $b$ is square or $n$ is even, then $b^n$ is square and hence $b^n - 1$ is not square. I've checked the residues of $5^n - 1$ with moduli up to 1000 and none of them directly rule it out as a square, so I suspect I'm missing something (number theory is not my field). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure whether there is an easier method , but it has been proven that the only perfect powers with difference $1$ are $8$ and $9$ and $8$ is not a perfect square. This was Catalan's conjecture, but now it is a theorem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371919/solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation

Comment: @lhf I don't think so. My answer links to Dietrich's comment there, but note [Mike Bennett's comment](/questions/3371919/solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation#comment6941781_3371919) just below states "The Lebesgue proof is for the "easier" case and does not extend to the proposed equation $a^2−1=b^n$." In other words, Dietrich's suggestion was a mistake. Although the Diophantine equations are similar, the change from $-1$ here to $+1$ there can make a large difference, not only in terms of what the solutions are, but also how difficult it's to solve, as Mike's comment indicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to solve your problem using congruence conditions, in particular dealing with your remaining case of $b \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Instead, consider if $b^n - 1$ is a perfect square, i.e., for some integer $m$ we have

$$b^n - 1 = m^2 \; \; \to \; \; b^n - m^2 = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

This is a special case of [Catalan's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture), i.e., that

> the only solution in the natural numbers of $$x^{a}-y^{b}=1$$ for $a, b \gt 1, x, y \gt 0$ is $x = 3, a = 2, y = 2, b = 3$.

This was proven in $2002$ by Preda Mihăilescu. Since we have $m^2$ in \eqref{eq1A}, i.e., the exponent is $b = 2$ in the Catalan's conjecture equation, this shows there are no solutions to \eqref{eq1A}.

Note that \eqref{eq1A} was specifically solved earlier, as stated in [Dietrich Burde's comment](/questions/3371919/solutions-to-the-diophantine-equation?noredirect=1#comment6938514_3371919):

> Yes, there is the elemenatry proof by Victor Lebesgue from $1850$ for the case that one exponent is $2$. "‘Sur l’impossibilité en nombres entiers de l’equation $x^m=y^2+1$’, Nouv. Ann. Math. $9$ ($1850$).

Comment: Thank you very much for the pointer. Apparently Lebesgue solved this particular case of Catalan's conjecture so I likely won't need to use the full result. Definitely nontrivial!

Comment: [Lebesgue's solution](http://archive.numdam.org/article/NAM_1850_1_9__178_0.pdf). If you know a bit of basic algebraic number theory, it is quite straightforward.